# Trouble to Analyze Experimental Data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, modeling, repeated-measures

I'm having trouble to analyze the data I collected from experiments.

In my experimental design I'm testing how sound intensities and interval between sound stimuli influence the reflex response in rats.

### Test 1

In each experimental session I expose the rats to different intensities of sounds (three levels of intensities) with a fixed interval between the presentation. In the first session, I used a fixed interval of 10 second, and one week later I tested the same animals but with an interval of 20 seconds between the stimuli. I can't use mixed intervals, that is, I need to use either 10 seconds interval or 20 seconds interval. The images below ilustrate the data I got from those experiments.

[image: **Table 1:** Results got from an experimental session with interval between sound presentation set at 10s. During the experimental session, each rat is exposed to three sound intensity levels and its motor response mesured. The experimental session consisted of random presentations of these sound levels.]

**Table 1:** Results got from an experimental session with interval between sound presentation set at 10s. During the experimental session, each rat is exposed to three sound intensity levels and its motor response mesured. The experimental session consisted of random presentations of these sound levels.

[image: **Table 2:** Results got from an experimental session with interval between sound presentation set at 20s.]

**Table 2:** Results got from an experimental session with interval between sound presentation set at 20s.

I'm not sure what statistical test I should use to compare the response from the rats between the condition with the 10 seconds interval to the condition with 20 seconds interval. I tried to use the repeated mesure ANOVA in JASP (0.10.0.0), but it seems as if it was comparing 12 rats, not the same 6 animals I used in the entire experiment.

### Test 2

I did also a second experiment in which I varied the intensities of the sounds. In the first week a used intensities L1, L2 and L3 (three levels of the same factors) and a week later repeated the session but with intensities L4, L5 and L6 (again three different levels). For example, the data I collected are presented in the figures below. I take the average response for each sound intensity for each rat. Also, in each experimental sessions, the three levels of intensities are presented to the rat. I made two separated experiments, testing different sounds levels.

[image: **Table 3:** Data collected from experiment 1, testing the sound levels L1 (10 dB), L2 (20 dB) and L3 (30 dB). During the experimental session, each rat is exposed to three sound intensity levels and its motor response mesured. The experimental session consisted of random presentations of these sound levels. Interval set at 10s.]

**Table 3:** Data collected from experiment 1, testing the sound levels L1 (10 dB), L2 (20 dB) and L3 (30 dB). During the experimental session, each rat is exposed to three sound intensity levels and its motor response mesured. The experimental session consisted of random presentations of these sound levels. Interval set at 10s.

[image: **Table 4:** Data collected from experiment 1, testing the sound levels L4 (15 dB), L5 (25 dB) and L6 (35 dB). Interval set at 10s.]

**Table 4:** Data collected from experiment 1, testing the sound levels L4 (15 dB), L5 (25 dB) and L6 (35 dB). Interval set at 10s.

But I'm not sure if i need to treat those intensities as 6 levels of the same factor ("sound intensity"; table 5) or if i need to treat them as just three levels of the same factor comparing between the experimantal sessions (table 6). But if I did the last option, I have the same problem that the JASP seems to be analysing as if I had 12 rats and not just 6 rats. Again, I can't use mixed sound presentation, I need to use either the first configuration (L1, L2 and L3) or the second configuration (L4, L5 and L6).

[image: **Table 5:** Option 1 for the statistical test]

**Table 5:** Option 1 for the statistical test

[image: **Table 6:** Option 2 for the statistical test]

**Table 6:** Option 2 for the statistical test

Is that correct? Or should I use another test to compare those results?

Comment: This is not very clear. What are the treatments L1, L2 and L3, and what are ... L4, L5 and L6? You need to be more careful giving context for this to be answerable.

Comment: I added some informations and tables, I hope it got clearer. Thanks.